# multiple definition of Scripting::LState

Tags: c++

The following code doesn't compile.
Linker outputs this error: `multiple definition of 'Scripting::LState'; /tmp/RandomLetters.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here`.
I'm using GCC 7.3.1 with GNU Binutils 2.31.1 with arguments:
`gcc src/scripting/**.cc src/main.cc -llua -lstdc++`

Here's the code:
`main.cc`

```
#include "includes/scripting.hpp"

int main() {
    Scripting::Init();
    Scripting::Close();
}
```

`includes/scripting.hpp`

```
extern "C" {
    #include <lua.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
    #include <lualib.h>
}

#ifndef SCRIPTING_H
#define SCRIPTING_H

namespace Scripting {
    lua_State *LState;
    int Init();
    int Close();
};

#endif
```

`scripting/main.cc`

```
#include "../includes/scripting.hpp"

int Scripting::Init() {
    LState = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(LState);

    luaL_loadstring(LState, "print('Hello World!');");

    return 0;
}

int Scripting::Close() {
    lua_close(LState);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the duplicate inclusion of scripting.hpp (in both main.cc files), gives you a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you define a variable in your header file. If that is included by multiple source files, you have multiple definitions when linking them together. Just declare the name in the header file like that:

```
namespace Scripting {
extern lua_State *LState;
...
```

So you only declare the variable and tell the compiler it exists somewhere external, so he knows the name LState.

Then in one source file define the variable (you want to use `scripting/main.cc` for this, where the methods are defined, too):

```
lua_State* Scripting::LState = nullptr; // Or some other value
```

Comment: Thanks! Using extern and nullptring the LState worked and now my stuff actually compiles!

Comment: It did compile before, too the linkage was the problem ;)